# Vim: keyword coloring

Tags: vim

Lately I came up here with a similar question. I want to color special words in all files
independet from the active syntax-file. It works with words like DONE and ADD.
I tried to achieve the same with [+] or [x] and [-] but it doesn't work.
[+] and so on them not to be interpreted as keyword. Fooling around with iskeyword+=[+] and
escaping the bracktes [+] didn't help.
The following line is in the .vimrc:

```
syn keyword tododone DONE ADD \[+\] containedin=ALL
```

As mentioned DONE and ADD work but not [+]. 
Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The keyword would have to be made up only of keyword characters (see `:help 'iskeyword'`), so [+] won't work: you'll have to use a match:

```
syn match tododone /\[+\]/ containedin=ALL
syn keyword tododone DONE ADD containedin=ALL
```

See:

```
:help syn-match
:help syn-keyword
```